# setIntercellSpacing: error

Tags: objective-c

How do you use this method properly, I get "Conversion to non-scalar type requested" upon compile. When executing the method like so: `[tableView setIntercellSpacing:(NSSize)(4.0, 5.0)];`

Any Ideas? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh wait, got it.

This is how you do it: `[tableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(2.0, 5.0)];`

Comment: You can try to use [tableView setIntercellSpacing:(NSSize){4.0, 5.0}]; but correct answer of course is using NSMakeSize function